# how to fire OnClientClick after validate regular expression in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to fire javascript function once validation of button click fire.

On Button Click

1. Fire Regular/Required expression(according to validation group)
2. Javascript function
3. Submit function of .CS file

   ```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchName" runat="server" class="search-input"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="scp-authvalidation" ID="req_txtSearchName" ControlToValidate="txtSearchName" ErrorMessage="" ValidationGroup="vg_search" />
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="vg_search" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  OnClientClick="callJavascriptFunction()" />

   //js function
   function callJavascriptFunction() {
          //some code
   }

   //cs function
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is only fire the server side click if the js function succeeds. to do that, your js function should return true/false depending on whether it validates or not.

once you have that, then simply add this to you server button. so if the validation returns false, the service side call will not fire.

```
OnClientClick="return callJavascriptFunction()"
```

Comment: No, I want to fire client click(javascript) once Validation check. 1- Check validation: This validations are of RegularExpression(ASP). 2- Call Javascript function, 3- Call Server side click. (Current flow is 2, 1, 3)